# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and I get the following error when I write this in the command line interface:

```
hold = {21, 22, {23, 24}, 25}
#=> SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

Shouldn't this being creating pairs

```
#=> {21 => 22, {23,24}=>25}
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using now?

Comment: What your are expecting works in Perl but not in Ruby

Comment: hashes are key-value pairs - Ruby does not have tuples.

Comment: What do you mean by `{23,24}`?

Answer (score 5):

Ruby's [hash literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes) `{ }` expects comma separated key-value *pairs* in the form `key => value`:

```
{ 1 => 'a', 2 => 'b' }    #=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b"}
{ :foo => 1, :bar => 2 }  #=> {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
```

If key is a symbol, you can also use the shorter `key: value` syntax (note that the resulting hash is identical to the one above):

```
{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }        #=> {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
```

You could use [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) to pass the keys and values as separate arguments:

```
Hash[21, 22, Hash[23, 24], 25]
#=> {21=>22, {23=>24}=>25}
```

But it's very uncommon to create a hash like that.